# in C++, is it more efficient to have "if" outside of a for loop or have the "if" in the for loop

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, loop-invariant

I am writing a program in C++ and I am debating whether to put the "if"s inside the loop. I would imagine doing one check and then looping would be overall more efficient rather than the constant loop and check, but I am not quite sure. Or does any of this not matter because the compiler will optimize it anyway?

Is this more efficient?

```
for(int i = 0; i < SOME_BOUND; i++){
    if(SOME_CONDITION){
        //Some actions
    }
    else {
        //Some actions
    }

}
```

or is this more efficient?

```
if(SOME_CONDITION){
    for(int i = 0; i < SOME_BOUND; i++){
        //Some Actions
    }
}
else {
    for(int i = 0; i < SOME_BOUND; i++){
        //Some Actions
    }
}
```

Comment: By the time the compiler's optimization kicks in, there is no difference.

Comment: Depends on what your program needs to do. I dont think there's any difference in efficiency.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's highly dependent on the details of `SOME_CONDITION`, the loop body, and whether any of it involves calls to library functions that the compiler can't see into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One check is definitely better, however there are features both in hardware (branch prediction) and compiler (hoisting expressions and conditionals outside the loop) which make it hard to predict whether there will actually be a runtime difference between the two pieces of source code.

Generally you should focus on correctness and maintainability, and only go duplicating loops for performance reasons if profiling shows that the optimizer is missing out on performance.

Comment: ahh ok. I am making a sine tone oscillator so I guess to help with buffer times and what not I would do the multiple loop definition.

Comment: The optimization of turning loop-invariant branching into separate loops is called Loop Unswitching ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching)). If compilers don't manage to do it for you, it can help a lot to do it manually for loops that can auto-vectorize.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can probably figure this out for you so that it executes it in the most efficient way. You should do what is more intuitive for your problem.

At a high level, doing the `if` only once is faster than doing it on every iteration of a loop, but again you should do what is more clear.